# Error on Blazor FileInput upload - The format of value '' is invalid

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I am using Blazor wasm net8.0, I can use the `FileInput` to upload most file types like images, pdfs, text, video, etc. But when I randomly selected a `.nupkg` file, it doesn't attempt the upload at all. It just writes in the console `The format of value '' is invalid. dotnet.native.8.0.0.fdi2l3wiik.js:8`

The debugger says it is this line `out(UTF8ArrayToString(tty.output, 0));` expanded below:

```js
                put_char: function(tty, val) {
                    if (val === null || val === 10) {
                        out(UTF8ArrayToString(tty.output, 0));
                        tty.output = []
                    } else {
                        if (val != 0)
                            tty.output.push(val)
                    }
                },
```

I'm not sure why it would fail to even try to start the upload, I'm not attempting to restrict by any file type. Afaik it should take any file.

Comment: Perhaps worth opening an issue on dotnet the aspnetcore GH: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore